# Rename Uploded file While Uploading

Tags: php, file, rename

i am not very much familier with php. so here is my code

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = $dirPath;
        $new_filename = strtotime("now").'-'.preg_replace("![^a-z0-9.]+!i", "_", $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
        $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' .$new_filename;

        $thumb_size = $this -> get_option('_thumb_size');
        $thumb_size = ($thumb_size == '') ? 75 : $thumb_size;

        $type = substr(strrchr($new_filename,'.'),1);

        if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){

            if (($type == "gif") || ($type == "jpeg") || ($type == "png") || ($type == "JPG") || ($type == "jpg") )
                $this -> create_thumb($targetPath, $new_filename, $thumb_size);

            $response['status']     = 'uploaded';
            $response['filename']   = $new_filename;
        }

        else{
            $response['status']     = 'error';
            $response['message']    = __('Error while uploading file', $this -> plugin_shortname);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    die(0);
}
```

i want that when someone send their image they can rename image before submit, like here in link.
http://www.desicomments.com/submit-pictures/

and mine is like that
http://www.punjabidharti.com/upload-pictures/

in my code it gives a new name but i want that user can select their name. thx

Comment: I don't think that what you showed us [here](http://www.desicomments.com/submit-pictures/) actually allows the uploader to change the image filename, rather it allows the uploader to assign a Title to the image which is then stored somewhere, that being a database or perhaps by embedding IPTC info into a JPEG converted image.

Comment: For one thing, PHP is recognizing your `__` in `$response['message']    = __('Error while uploading file'` immediately as a "construct", unless that's your intention.

Answer (score 0):

well you need use AJAX to get preview and put the textbox
you can check this tutorial
[upload files with ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)